# Conditional Subjunctive

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, conditionnel

So, I was wondering what one would say if one had to use the conditional with a conjunction that takes the subjunctive. “J’y allais, quoiqu’elle n’irait pas.” Is this a good example? Does one just use the conditional or something else, in colloquial usage at least? Seeing that I’m not sure how the subjunctive is used here.

I tried to say that “I was going there, although she would not (i.e., refused to) go.”

Comment: The lower part of [this *CNRTL-TFLi* entry for "quoique"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoique) gives some "particular cases" (apparently rejected by "purists") and some other familiar ones that use moods/tenses other than the subjunctive (including, but not only, the conditional). I can't really tell if your example fits any of these "particular/familiar cases," but their existence does at least show that you're in pretty good company in wondering if the subjunctive is always the best way to express an idea introduced by "quoique" (Balzac & Sartre,among others), so +1 for that!

Comment: So in colloquial usage at least, would one use the conditional here if needed? Seeing that I’m not sure how the subjunctive is used here.

Comment: ThatLanguageGuy asked: "So in colloquial usage at least, would one use the conditional here if needed? Seeing that I’m not sure how the subjunctive is used here." .... Maybe the biggest "problem" is whether using/wanting to use "quoique" here is justified in the first place (ie, is there a strong/obvious enough reverse/contrary-to-expectations connection between the 2 clauses?). Does "elle n'irait pas" in your example mean "I was going even tho **she would not (refused to) go**" or "...even tho **she would not be going**" or "...even tho **she would rather not go**" or something else?

Comment: @PapaPoule I tried to say that “I was going there, although she would not (i.e., refused to) go.”

Comment: Please take all with a grain of salt, but even w/that strongest (refused to go") meaning, I'm thinking that a simple "mais" could connect these 2 clauses w/out the issues caused by using "quoique." Of course, if it's a couple who **always** does things/is seen together, then I get the desire/need to emphasize the "contrary to what you'd think" notion conveyed by "quoique," but in that case I'd be tempted to rewrite it as something like: "J'y allais/irai/s/(?je vais/veux/voudrai/voudrais/voulais?) y aller, quoiqu'elle n'y soit/sera/it pas/ne veuille/voudrait pas y aller/elle refuse d'y aller."

Comment: @PapaPoule D’accord ! Je vois bien maintenant comment écrire une phrase pareille. Merci pour vos conseils et votre aide. Bonne journée

Comment: J’y allais, quoiqu’elle n’y irait pas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic seems to be encountered in FSE again in the past:

[Conditional/past conditional + subjunctive?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23859/conditional-past-conditional-subjunctive)

It is still an ongoing issue for the grammarians (see the links in the aforementioned discussion).

**I was going there, although she would not (i.e., refused to) go.**

Here is my attempt:

> J'y allais, même si elle ne voulait pas aller.
>
> Malgré son refus d'aller, j'y allais.
>
> Bien/Quoi qu'elle n'aurait pas voulu aller, j'y allais.